# Kendo ui web upload to extract txt file contents and record it to a database

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4, data-extraction

Step 1 - Select txt file with kendo upload

(either upload it to a database at this stage or to app_data folder to be deleted later or another method)

Step 2 - Extract data from the txt file

(? depending on step 1 I would select the file I uploaded or is in app_data or ... then put it through a file steam or something to grab all the text inside)

Step 3 - Assign extracted data to a table model to record back to a database

I should only be dealing with a single file at a time which I would also wonder if I can restrict kendo upload to allow only single files per upload if it's even needed for me to upload the file.

Comment: What did you try so far? We wont do the job for you ;)

Comment: @Pabloker Well I've been working with kendo ui but that's only too upload a file directly to database and ideally I want to skip that step and just use it as a selector unless it's necessary that I have to upload the file to a database 1st, otherwise I've looked through tons of possible examples for data extraction but all have slightly different approaches which most aren't compatible with what I want to do it leaves me stuck like this example"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228292/upload-excel-file-and-extract-data-from-it-and-put-that-data-in-database-using-m"

Comment: There have been at least 20-30 other links I've looked at but nothing concrete which covers step 1-3 just step 2-3 or 1 or different systems like php etc.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to do file processing in the browser, correct? If so, I do recommend to split the problem in two: 1) Upload file to the database (nothing special here!); 2) Read file from JavaScript (try googling for "javascript file reading"). You will learn about how to do it (and limitations).

Comment: @OnaBai I'll look into both yours and Spikes solution now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kendo Music Store sample app has an example of an ASP.NET WebAPI controller reading a posted file (an image in this case, but file contents doesn't matter) and saving it to the file system: [ImagesController.cs](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/Controllers/Api/ImagesController.cs)

You could do something similar; read the file contents off the ASP.NET request, and do whatever processing you want.

The HTML and Javascript that set up the Kendo upload widget is in: [storemanager-index.js](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/Scripts/App/storemanager-index.js)

And finally a little bit of documentation from the Kendo Music Store tutorial docs: [Album Art Upload With The Kendo Upload Widget](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-management-grid#album-art-upload-with-the-kendo-upload-widget)

Comment: Luckily the project was dropped as it would of wasted dev time to same min effort for staff which didn't use existing system they've been provided.  As it seemed useful at the time and close to helping solve the problem I'm marking this correct.